# Custom domain name for github project page

Tags: github

I have a jekyll blog hosted on my github account and I have attached a domain to it http://blog.myname.com

I also created a github page for one of my repositories, it is hosted by github as this my-github-username.com/github-page

My question is how can I attach a new domain name to my repository, like when I goto myrepo.com it will show my repo's github page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to change `CNAME` record of `myrepo.com` point into `my-github-username.com/github-page`

For detail config please look at this link [github](https://help.github.com/articles/about-custom-domains-for-github-pages-sites#how-github-pages-sites-use-custom-domains)

And i think this link also help you to set goal [How GitHub Pages sites use custom domains](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-cname-file-to-your-repository#examples-of-real-world-cname-files)